# Maximum of the Mellin transform

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, mellin-transform

I need to find the maximum of the Mellin transform $K(s)$ of the function $k(x)$, whose definition is
$$K(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}k(x)dx$$
The answer is that the maximum of $K(s)$ is at $s=1$. But I have problems to derive it.

My attempt: In order to find the maximum I need to find the $s$ that satisfy
$$K'(s)=0.$$
So I need to take the derivative of the integral above. At first, I thought I should apply the 1st Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I'm not so sure if this theorem is useful here since this a definite integral. By this theorem, if
$$F(t)=\int_a^t x^{s-1}k(x)dx$$
then
$$F'(t)=t^{s-1}k(t)$$
Roughly speaking, we derive wrt $x$ and then we substitute $x$ by $t$ to obtain  $F'(t)$:
$$\int \frac{d}{dx}x^{s-1}k(x)dx=\int d(x^{s-1}k(x))=x^{s-1}k(x) \to F'(t)=t^{s-1}k(t) $$
But it is not the same case as $K(s)$, because in this integral we have sumed over all the $x's$, then the result is a function that depends only on $s$, and we have to derive $K(s)$ wrt $s$, whereas in $F(t)$ the derivative is wrt $x$ . That is why  I think this theorem  doesn't work out here.

I also  tried to prove  it by the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{ds}K(s)=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}k(x)dx=\int_0^\infty  \frac{d}{dx} ( x^{s-1}k(x))  \frac{dx}{ds}  dx  =\int_0^\infty [ (s-1)x^{s-2}k(x)+x^{s-1}k'(x)]\frac{dx}{ds} dx$$
But then I don't see how this integrand would be equal to zero. If the second term of the integrand wasn't there, we'd obtain the answer. So I am wondering whether, as
$s$ only appears in $x^{s-1}$, the chain rule only affect this term, I mean:

$$\frac{d}{ds}K(s)=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}k(x)dx=\int_0^\infty  \frac{d}{dx} ( x^{s-1} \frac{dx}{ds}) k(x)  dx  = \int_0^\infty (s-1)x^{s-2}\frac{dx}{ds} k(x) dx $$
The problem is that, as the derivative wrt $s$ doesn't affect $k(x)$, I am assuming that $x$ doesn't depend on $s$, then $dx/ds=0$, and $K'(s)$ would be zero for all $s$.

I would appreciate if you could point out the serious mistakes I've commited  as much as any help you could bring me to solve this problem.

Comment: There shouldn’t be a chain rule or an $x$-derivative anywhere. Assuming some convergence properties, you can just pass the $s$-derivative inside the integral. The $k(x)$ is constant in $s$ so you only need to differentiate $x^{s-1}$ with respect to $s$, which should give $\ln(x) x^{s-1}$. It’s not clear to me that this easily implies that $K’(1)=0$; maybe if you know something about $k(x)$ you could make a substitution like $y=1/x$ or $y=ax$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: that substitution you mentioned, how would it help?

Comment: Not sure they would, but $y=1/x$ is a natural substitution when $\ln(x)$ is present and $y=ax$ is a natural substitution when you are integrating against $dx/x$ so those are the ones that came to mind. No clue if they will help.